# Why compilation with a lot of \lstinputlisting is so slow?

Tags: listings, compiling

I'm using a lot of `\lstinputlisting` in my document and the compilation of it is really slow. Why it takes so long? How could I make things better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, `\lstinputlisting` does a lot of parsing which takes time. The [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for the listings package mentions the option `savemem` which can reduce compile time if you use a lot of languages. Or use the `draft` option to print only captions and define labels, but omit the actual listing.

I have in my current document an appendix with a lot of listings. I omit the appendix with the versions package to save some time.

Comment: Thanks. The `savemem` didn't actually save me any noticable time. I even use `\lstloadlanguages` just like manual says, but that didn't do either. But the `draft` works just fine for me